# Create Array with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, google-maps

i'm creating a map with google maps api.

Basically, the array structure to call any markers is like this:

```
var station = [
['SEDRANO DI SAN QUIRINO (PN)',46.048887,12.657924,'Via Maniago, 28','Tel. 0434 918900','sedrano-di-san-quirino.jpg',true,true,false,false,false,false,false],
['CORTINA D\'AMPEZZO (BL)',46.541307,12.132348,'Via dello Stadio, 7','Tel.  0436 869133','cortina-dampezzo.jpg',true,true,false,false,false,true,false],
['POINCICCO DI ZOPPOLA (PN)',45.948725,12.745332,'Via Cusano, 14','Tel. 0434 574831','poinciccio-di-zoppola.jpg',true,true,false,false,false,true,false]
];
```

Now, i would create an array with json calls, so... **first step** i call markers with **php** and put these in json_encode

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markers");
$rows = array();
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
 }
print json_encode($rows);
```

**result**

```
[{"city":"SEDRANO DI SAN QUIRINO (PN)","lat":"46.0489","lng":"12.6579","address":"Via Maniago, 28","phone":"Tel. 0434 918900","thumb":"http:\/\/www.costantin.com\/images\/thumb\/maps\/sedrano-di-san-quirino.jpg","top-verde":"false","top-diesel":"false","gpl":"false","lavaggio":"false","cafe":"false","verde":"true","diesel":"true","id":"1"},{"city":"CORTINA D'AMPEZZO (BL)","lat":"46.5413","lng":"12.1323","address":"Via dello Stadio, 7","phone":"Tel. 0436 869133","thumb":"http:\/\/www.costantin.com\/images\/thumb\/maps\/cortina-dampezzo.jpg","top-verde":"false","top-diesel":"false","gpl":"false","lavaggio":"true","cafe":"false","verde":"true","diesel":"true","id":"2"},{"city":"POINCICCO DI ZOPPOLA (PN)","lat":"45.9487","lng":"12.7453","address":"Via Cusano, 14","phone":"Tel. 0434 574831","thumb":"http:\/\/www.costantin.com\/images\/thumb\/maps\/poinciccio-di-zoppola.jpg","top-verde":"false","top-diesel":"false","gpl":"false","lavaggio":"true","cafe":"false","verde":"true","diesel":"true","id":"3"}]
```

**secondo step** i call with jquery getJSON datas, like this...

```
$.getJSON( "markers.php", function( data ) {
    var station = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    station.push( data );
  });
});
```

But this is totally out of work, so... in which way i could do it?
So... is there a way to accomplish this structure?

```
  var station = [
    ['SEDRANO DI SAN QUIRINO (PN)',46.048887,12.657924,'Via Maniago, 28','Tel. 0434 918900','sedrano-di-san-quirino.jpg',true,true,false,false,false,false,false],
    ['CORTINA D\'AMPEZZO (BL)',46.541307,12.132348,'Via dello Stadio, 7','Tel.  0436 869133','cortina-dampezzo.jpg',true,true,false,false,false,true,false],
    ['POINCICCO DI ZOPPOLA (PN)',45.948725,12.745332,'Via Cusano, 14','Tel. 0434 574831','poinciccio-di-zoppola.jpg',true,true,false,false,false,true,false]
    ];
```

Comment: according to http://jsonlint.com/ your goal isn't a valid json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stations = []; //You need an external variable to hold all the stations

$.getJSON( "markers.php", function( data ) {
    //var station = []; //Don't need this here

    //"data" is an array, not a key/value object
    /*$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        //You are adding the JSON "data" array here, not the values
        station.push( data );
    });*/

    //Remember "data" is a JSON array, not object
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        var station = []; //Temporary variable to hold station data

        //Iterate over the current station object
        $.each(data[i], function(key, value) { 
          station.push(value); //You're not interested in the key
        });
        stations.push(station); //Add station to array of all stations
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't fetch associative arrays if you only care about the array value, try this:

```
$rows = array();
 while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
  $rows[] = array_values($r);
 }
print json_encode($rows);
```